# How to unlock the Bandolier via 'ammo caches'?

Tags: prodeus

Aside from buying the Bandolier as a tier3 item at the shop, [I've read](https://prodeus.fandom.com/wiki/Bandolier) you can unlock it by other means, after accessing some secret exits in *Chaos Generator* and *Marksman* and hitting some switches.  However, I've gone so far as to look up videos of accessing the secret exit of at least *Chaos Generator* and I'm stumped; either the secrets have been patched/changed or the guides I've seen are simply not very clear.

In the image below, you see the initial secret ore hiding spot in *Chaos Generator*, which under *some circumstance* is supposed to open up further revealing the secret exit, but I've done everything in the map with no success.

[image: Access tunnel is not there]

How do I unlock the Bandolier, which stages are the secrets located in, and how do you access them?

Comment: Will this help? https://prodeus.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Exit

Comment: No, not at all, as the secret exit listed for Chaos Generator doesn't seem to be there for me, or there is some additional step to access it that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this problem, then I noticed that the guides on YouTube and Fandom pointed out that this setting may only be limited to the 'Early Access' stage. So these settings may have been deleted in our existing version.

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HyALYq898A)</sup>

[image]
<sup>[source](https://prodeus.fandom.com/wiki/Marksman)</sup>